# Lightbox: Highslide and Colorbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox, highslide

Well the main one I'm working with is Highslide, but I've tried both now.

My problem is the background doesn't fade when a selected image pops up in the lightbox window.

I have tried both Highslide and Colorbox, same issue.  I've also tried all browsers and the same thing is happening across all of them.

Highslide is my preference.  I have highslide.js and highslide.css both linked to my page with no errors.  I have highslide called with an `<a>` link and it is working just fine.  All except for the semi-transparent fading of the background upon selection which is not happening.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a syntax error. The script tag in HTML is not self-closing. you can't do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highslide-full.min.js" />
```

It must be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
```

You should always run your page through a validator to catch things like this. It can save you hours of debugging!

Once that error is fixed, make sure that highslide.css is getting loaded (it's probably just the  syntax error immediately preceding it that's preventing highslide.css from loading).

Comment: Any idea why when I use the highslide.min.js I can go straight from one image to another and with the highslide-full.min.js I have to close the open one before I can bring the next up?  Meaning when one image is open I still have the magnifying glass and can click on another image and closes one and opens the next in one motion.  Whereas with the later I get just a pointer arrow and have to close the open on then click on another to view.
I don't see anything in the settings for this.
Thanks EO!

Comment: highslide.js (and highslide.min.js) is just a subset of the full script. It doesn't include the "transitions" needed to move from one image to the next. Just stick with highslide-full.js (or highslide-full.min.js), which includes all the functionality. There's no reason to use the pared-down version.

Comment: I did! XD  It's ok how it is and obviously I have to use the full.js for the faded background, but that functionality is a really nice feature. Can't figure why it only works that way with the standard hs.js file.  Check it out now and see what I mean.  Much better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using highslide-full.js, and not just highslide.js, which is just a subset of the full script, and doesn't include the background dimming you're after. Then in your Highslide configuration, set the dimming opacity with a value from 0 (no dimming) to 1 (completely black):

hs.dimmingOpacity=0.75;

If it's still not working, a link to your page would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply EO.  I first unlinked highslide.js, then linked highslide-full.min.js, adjusted the mentioned setting cleared cache and tried it.  Same thing happening.
I looked closer at your post and then unlinked/relinked highslide-full.js, changed the settings I found, cleared cache and tried again.  Same thing happening.
The dimmingOpacity I do not find in highslide-full.js.
The site is still in dev but here's a link:
http://swdllcdev.com/index.php?id=3

Comment: Add this to the HTML in the page, AFTER loading highslide-full.js:
<script type="text/javascript">
hs.dimmingOpacity = 0.7;
</script>

Comment: Oh, and there's nothing wrong with using highslide-full.min.js, which is a minified version of highslide-full.js. It's smaller, so it might load a tiny bit faster.

Comment: bah I don't know. that doesn't work either. It's really ok just like it is. Would be slightly better with the fade.
I tried inserting the setting script just before the images calls then just inside the body close. Same outcome.
I tried removing the js menu and email scripts so hs was alone.  Still same. Just weird.
The standard highslide.js seems better because for some reason you can click another image without closing the first.
I don't get why all the other settings I change within the js file work except the fade.  Seems like an issue outside highslide causing a conflict.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the hs.dimmingOpacity setting on your test page. And now I notice that highslide.css seems to be missing. This is critical for Highslide JS to function properly.

Comment: Ya I had just taken it back out. Take a look now.

Comment: The css file link was never removed.  I'm putting the js link back to highslide.min.js now.  It functions better for some reason.  The setting script seems to do nothing no matter what js file I link.  If you have any other ideas feel free to post up, but as of now nothing worked to fix the fading background.

Comment: See my answer above, about the script tag (the "comment" feature on here makes it impossible to post code). The highslide.css file is simply never being loaded, probably because of that syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Was a combo of both the HS Full file and the closing script tag.